# If $\phi:G \to \overline G$ is group homomorphism, then prove that $|\phi(G)|$ divides $|G|$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

If $\phi:G \to \overline G$ is group homomorphism, then prove that $|\phi(G)|$ divides $|G|$, where $|G|$ is finite.
One way to prove this is this: we know that $\phi:G \to \phi(G)$ is an $n$-to-$1$ mapping, where $n=\lvert\ker \phi\rvert$. So $|\phi (G)|\cdot n=|G|$.

Is there any other short proof of it? Thanks.

Comment: (Provided $|G|$ is finite).

Comment: Yes, of course.

Comment: I don't know of a short alternate proof.  I could use the fundamental theorem, but that's really using the same idea.

Comment: Easy. Prove that $\phi(G)$ is a subgroup of the target group. Then use Lagrange's Theorem.

Comment: @the_fox That only shows that $|\phi(G)|$ divides $|\overline{G}|$, not $|G|$.

Comment: Ah, sorry. I misread.

Comment: Yeah, I think I agree with Michael Burr. I don't see any way to prove that without invoking (directly or indirectly) the First Isomorphism Theorem.

Comment: You could use the *proof* of Lagrange's theorem to show that $|Ker\phi||G/Ker\phi| = |G|$ and the first isomorphism theorem to show $G/Ker\phi \simeq \phi(G)$ but it's essentially the same thing and I don't know if it's shorter

Comment: @Max You don't need anything other than the First Isom. Thm.

Answer (score -1):

Your proof is the shortest I know. Here it is again with more detail:

Consider the fibers of $\phi$ given by $\phi^{-1}(b)$ for $b\in \overline G$:

- $b \notin \phi(G) \implies \phi^{-1}(b)=\emptyset$.
- $b \in \phi(G) \implies b=\phi(a), \ a \in G \implies \phi^{-1}(b)=a\ker\phi$.

Therefore, all fibers have the same number of elements. The claim follows because the number of fibers is exactly $|\phi(G)|$.